# Android notifications: open Activity and run BroadcastReceiver when tapping a button using multiple PendingIntents

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

**What I want to achieve:** my notification has a button. When user taps it, I want to move the app to the foreground and do some background work simultaneously.

To achieve the first one, I would use `PendingIntent` like this:

```
val mySingleActivityAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    Random.nextInt(),
    Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```

For the second one, I declared a broadcast receiver that in its `onReceive` do some background logic. And the `PendingIntent` looks like this:

```
val myBroadcastReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context,
    Random.nextInt(),
    Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
```

Then normally I would create a `NotificationCompat.Action` using `Builder`, example:

```
val notificationButtonAction = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
    0,
    "Click me",
    one_of_these_two_pending_intents
).build()
```

and add it to `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

However, I'm not able to add many `PendingIntent`s to that action as it only accepts one. So I can either open the app, or do the background logic, not both of them.

There was no problem prior to Android 10 as we could always launch an `Activity` from `BroadcastReceiver`. But starting from Android 10, it's [not possible](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) as apps from background should not start activities. They suggest handling it using... notification but I'm just coming from the notification click!

Any ideas how to deal with that situation?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to move the app to the foreground and do some background work simultaneously

Have the activity start the background work.

If you also need to use this activity in a mode where it does not start this background work, use an `Intent` extra, an `Intent` action string, or some in-memory flag to state that this is a scenario where you want the background work to be performed.

Comment: Will it change anything that whole app is written in Compose? I mean, my MainActivity is just a host for navigation logic (`NavHost` etc).

Comment: @adek111: "Will it change anything that whole app is written in Compose?" -- I would not expect it to.